# Call previous sibling as function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a wee letter-writing tool that will have a range of paragraphs the user can choose to add to a letter, but I worry that I'm doing it in a really inefficient way.

Currently, it's structured like this:

```
<p id="deposit-dispute" class="paragraph">This is a paragraph about deposits not being protected</p>
<button onclick="addPara(depositDispute)" class="add">Add paragraph</button>
```

and then in the Javascript, I create a const that pulls the inner HTML of that id:

```
const depositDispute = "\n" + document.getElementById("deposit-dispute").innerHTML + "\n";
```

which the addPara() function then adds to the textarea:

```
function addPara(text) {
document.getElementById("text-body").value += text;
}
```

But would there be a way to make the function just call whatever the previous *p* element had in it, rather than having to give them all unique IDs and creating a unique variable for them all?

Here it is in a codepen so you can see what I'm trying to do - the paragraphs to be added are in the accordion on the right: https://codepen.io/gordonmaloney/pen/GRWyjOP

Thanks a lot - and big apologies if this is a ridiculously amateurish question, I've spent ages trying to google a solution but can't find a thing!

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `box` contains a *paragraph* and a *button*.
We can get all the `boxes` and each `box` *paragraph* and *button*, and finally add `click event` to the `button` to insert the `paragraph html` of this `box` to the `textarea`

```js
// Get textarea and boxes
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

// get the button and the paragraph of each box 
boxes.forEach(box => {
    var btn = box.querySelector('.button');
    var paragraph = box.querySelector('.paragraph');
    // add the html of the selected box paragraph to the textarea 
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        textarea.value += "\n" + paragraph.innerHTML; + "\n";
    });
});
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box">
          <p class="paragraph">This is paragraph 1</p>
          <button class="button">Add to textarea</button>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
          <p class="paragraph">This is paragraph 2</p>
          <button class="button">Add to textarea</button>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
          <p class="paragraph">This is paragraph 3</p>
          <button class="button">Add to textarea</button>
      </div>
 </div>
  
 <textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That is perfect - don't 100% understand what you've done though  Will spend some time digesting it, really appreciate your help